# How to create an emboss effect for a tablix in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Is there any way to create an emboss effect for a tablix, or any other "cool" effects for a tablix in SSRS 2008 R2?

Comment: Please tale look at this [MSDN Link: Background color alternate in tablix for group ](http://msdn.eeyogo.com/sqlreportingservices-thread/background-color-alternate-in-tablix-for-group-not-individual-rows.html)

Comment: That will create an effect of contrast between columns, right? I'm really looking for something to show some emboss, or depth for the whole tablix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emboss is not available as an out of the box option with SSRS. IF you really need that effect, you can simulate it by placing rectangles in a table, and then placing a textbox in those. You can then shade different sides of the textbox different colors.

I personally would avoid embossed looking things. I think they usually look bad, especially when printed. If you want to look cool, and keep things easy in SSRS, I recommend these things to go in a more "metro" direction.

**Use Color**

Choose and use a consistent color palette for a project, across multiple reports. If you aren't a designer-type, go to the company website, and sample some of the colors there.

Typically you can find:

- a dark color to use for title text
- a lighter color for subheadings
- a medium color for occasional accent, such as behind the title, or a line below the title
- a much lighter color (used in sidebars on websites) that you can set as the background to your table headers.

**Pay attention to Type**

Use the same font for all pieces of the report. You might get away with using a different font for the title, but usually it will look bad.
Use Italics and Bold as needed. *Italics* type should be used for incidental data details, that are not the focus of the report. **Bold** should be used for titles, sub headings, and a key data element, especially if the data is more than one line long.

**Consistent spacing**

Report elements that are close in size to each other should be the exact same size. This means that you won't be able to cram as much data in, but the report will be much more pleasant and professional to look at. I try to use either a half inch or .75 inch grid and make everything multiples of that size.  BIDS doesn't really support this, so this can involve some typing in of sizes.

If there are graphics, line those up with the grid as much as possible.

If you want to get serious about this, start reading books by [Edward Tufte](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/). In particular, [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961392142) is often considered a classic of information design.

Reports that are developed with this "less is more" attitude will look fresh and usable longer than reports full of distractions, aka Chart Junk.

Comment: Wow! What a lecture. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I hope it wasn't too much. I've just had these thoughts brewing for a bit and have meant to write something up. You gave me an opportunity.

Comment: On the contrary. I really appreciate your input. And I asked my boss to get the book for me! Thanks.